# Change the format of date and print.

Tags: java

I have a date in Java like this:

```
09-06-2009 00:00:00
```

I wish I could print them as :

```
2009-09-06 00:00:00
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Remember, Date is container for the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, in of itself, it has no defined format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

```
String DateStr="09-06-2009 00:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

As in your question nothing has been mentioned about this 09-06-2009 00:00:00 (dd-MM-yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy) so I did with MM-dd-yyyy

**output** `2009-09-06 00:00:00`

Answer (score 3):

**step**: 1   use SimpleDateFormat to transfer the date format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

**step**: 2   store your date in a String

```
String OldDate="09-06-2009 00:00:00";
```

**step**: 3  store the date to that format

```
Date oldDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(DateStr);
```

**step**: 4  change it to new format like this

```
sdf.format(oldDateformat );
```