# Java Date String to date same format

Tags: java, date

2013-06-24 15:43:00.0   this is Sting

i want parse that to Date

but in same formate

if Month is Month Jan it should be 1 etc

Comment: How about googling for "parse date in Java"?

Comment: Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and possible every other question about [String to Date](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+string+to+date)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has being asked and answered many times before and shows a complete lack of research

Comment: Do make some effort to formulate an understandable question and make some effort to search for existing documentation and answers first

Comment: Similar type of question I have answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754720/change-the-format-of-date-and-print/20754794#20754794 try and if you face any problem then post with your tried code

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
String dateString = "2013.06.24 15:43:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdfToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");

Date date1 = sdfToDate.parse(dateString);

System.out.println(sdfToDate.format(date1));
```

Comment: out put is Mon Jun 24 15:43:00 IST 2013

Comment: but i want 2013.06.24 15:43:00 as it is same

Comment: I edited it. Now your output is in the correct format. Just format() it when you want to print.

Comment: how can u help please

Comment: Try my code. It's what you want, right? First you use the SimpleDateFormat to parse the String into a Date, after that you use the SimpleDateFormat to format the date for the correct output.

Comment: can u give the code please i request you

Comment: can u give the code please i request you

Comment: My answer is the code.. i corrected my answer and now it works how you want it. Just try it out.

Comment: String dateString = "2013.06.24 15:43:00";

 SimpleDateFormat sdfToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date2 = sdfToDate.parse(dateString);
 System.out.println("date2"+date2);
 
 String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(date2.getDate());
 System.out.println("myDate "+myDate);